# Retrieving data from the mongoDB through React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am developing this simple app in Node, React and MongodDB(mongoose) where I can register the user and then I can edit the user's information. The thing is, I am stuck when it comes to display the content I just registered(Edit component). I wanted to display the user's info in the Edit component fields, which are the exact same as the Register component. I don't know how I would get this info back and display it.

```
class Register extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        email: '',
        telephone:''

    }
}

onEmailChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({email: event.target.value})
}

onTelephoneChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({telephone: event.target.value})
}

render () {
return (
  <article className="br3 ba b--black-10 mv4 w-100 w-50-m w-30-l shadow-5 center">  
            <main className="pa4 black-80">
            <div className="measure">
                <fieldset id="email" className="ba b--transparent ph0 mh0">
                    <div className="mt3">
                        <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6">Email</label>
                        <MaskedInput 
                            className="  borderColour pa2 input-reset ba bg-transparent hover-bg-black hover-white w-100" 
                            placeholder='john@email.com'
                            id="email"
                            required
                            onChange={this.onEmailChange}
                            /> 
                        <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6">Zona</label>
                            <div className="mv3">
                        <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6">Telefone</label>
                        <MaskedInput
                            className=" borderColour b pa2 input-reset ba bg-transparent hover-bg-black hover-white w-100"
                            placeholder="(41) 99989-0909" 
                            onChange={this.onTelephoneChange}
                            /> 
                    </div>

    </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </article>

);
}
}
```

I tried to shorten my code as the other fields are pretty much the same. 
I'd be glad if anyone could help me with that!

Comment: You need to expose an API for fetchig user data on the server. Then you need to hit this API. If you are looking for libraries to do that you can use expressjs/koa (NodeJS web frameworks) + mongoose (MongoDB object modeling tool). I hope I got your question right :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you should call your user API to get registered user information in componentDidMount and i have also add the code of default value in MaskInput tag this will work for you

```
class Register extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        email: '',
        telephone:''

    }
}
componentDidMount  = () => {
    //call your API and set value in email and telephone
    // Below are the sample code for call API, it will change as per your use
    const myHeaders = new Headers();

    myHeaders.append('x-api-key', 'KEY_HERE');
    myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    myHeaders.append('cache-control', 'no-cache')

    fetch('URL_HERE', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: myHeaders,
        async: true,
    }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            //check your json response and find email and telephone and then set it to our state
           //Below I have set state, you have to set this state as per your response                  
            this.setState({
                email: json.email,
                telephone: json.telephone,
            })
        });
}

onEmailChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({email: event.target.value})
}

onTelephoneChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({telephone: event.target.value})
}

render () {
return (
  <article className="br3 ba b--black-10 mv4 w-100 w-50-m w-30-l shadow-5 center">  
            <main className="pa4 black-80">
            <div className="measure">
                <fieldset id="email" className="ba b--transparent ph0 mh0">
                    <div className="mt3">
                        <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6">Email</label>
                        <MaskedInput
                            value={this.state.email} 
                            className="  borderColour pa2 input-reset ba bg-transparent hover-bg-black hover-white w-100" 
                            placeholder='john@email.com'
                            id="email"
                            required
                            onChange={this.onEmailChange}
                            /> 
                        <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6">Zona</label>
                            <div className="mv3">
                        <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6">Telefone</label>
                        <MaskedInput
                            value={this.state.telephone} 
                            className=" borderColour b pa2 input-reset ba bg-transparent hover-bg-black hover-white w-100"
                            placeholder="(41) 99989-0909" 
                            onChange={this.onTelephoneChange}
                            /> 
                    </div>

    </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </article>

);
}
}
```